# Android NullPointerException in a View or in an Adapter or

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I don't know where else to look, I'm getting crazy with this error. It's not coming from using a null variable and it appeared just restarting an app without changing any of the code. Anyone knows?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:911)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The lines where it happens

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You should pot your adapter code, the line where this happens.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706170/nullpointerexception-with-string-array-in-spinner

Comment: I think you are triyng to call *toString()* method of a null object. Please post your code.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference` - **It's not coming from using a null variable** - yes it is!  You are adding a null object to your listview.

Comment: values is null. Post the test of your code and we can tell you why.

Answer (score 5):

Although the question is years old, I want to post my answer, it can help other people in the future with this problem because there are no answers yet.

Check if there are null objects in`values`. For example, `String[5]` with only 4 set elements will cause this error, because ArrayAdapter is calling `toString()` internally on all elements.

Comment: eg i was adding a list(100 size but just one vale, rest all were null) to adapter  the null were giving error toString internal function of adapter. Hope this helps someone else ( i was stuck for 8 hours on silly non explanatory error)