# i added a spinner in the app but the activity is not starting due to adapter code

Tags: android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rishabh.casino/com.example.rishabh.casino.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Can you put the code? First you need to bind the Adapter variable to an xml element of initialize it programmatically.

Comment: @Josh i've put the code in an answer. or you can visit 
http://www.viewdocsonline.com/document/1k0t2o

Comment: [Check this out, probably this can help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706170/nullpointerexception-with-string-array-in-spinner

Comment: 1) Make sure that R.id.spinner, is in fact, inside the layout: R.layout.activity_game 2) Also, move these two lines to the beginning of the onCreate method just in case: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game); 3) Put the Logcat and your java code in the same question paragraph, or downvotes will start raining upobn you. Be a bit more organized please.

Answer (score 9):

Main problem is You are initializing your spinner above your view.
You should put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);` 
on top and after that you should initialize other components. Correct your `onCreate`

```
@Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game); //Initialize layout first

                    spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    rembal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                    bet_amount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
                    beton=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                    result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
                    bet=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    okgen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_option=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
                    adapter_option.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spin.setAdapter(adapter_option);
                    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                                .commit();
                    }
                }
```

This is the reason behind null pointer exception. View is not initialize yet and you are trying to initialize spinner inside view.

Answer (score 4):

From the error log looks like your spinner object is null...

this can be because you haven't initialized it (with findViewById("...")) or you did that but in one of latter calls...

Comment: i have initialized it .here's my code for the activity

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have put the spinner in the view dialog. Therefore, when invoking adaptor function, this error occurred. Simply I called as below and solved my problem:

```
 spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
```

Answer (score 0):

I shifted declaration of spinner just before attaching adapter

```
        Spinner sp;
        sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spUOM);
        sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

Earlier declatation was done in

```
public class Main2Activity
```

It solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

here's the code for activity

import..

```
public class Game extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner spin;
    TextView rembal;
    TextView bet_amount;
    TextView result;
    TextView beton;
    EditText bet;
    Button okgen;
    String options[]={"ODD NUMBER","EVEN NUMBER","PRIME NUMBER","MULTIPLE OF 3","EXACT NUMBER" };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        rembal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        bet_amount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        beton=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        bet=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        okgen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_option=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
        adapter_option.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter_option);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spin.setSelection(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        spin.setSelection(0);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your spinner in your fragment layout defined?

because in that case you should initiate it inside your fragment onCreateView, and set adapter in onActivityCreated..


other thing, these two lines: 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

should be first in activity onCreate method.

Answer (score -1):

You should define correct layout, also define spinner in onCreate() method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner);//layout
```