# None of my classes include in the stacktrace from Android developer console

Tags: android, debugging, developer-console

I received 4 crash reports from Android developer console with the same stacktrace, which seems to suggest a NullPointerException occured when the system is building the UI. However the trace does not include any of my class nor any of my layout file. Is there anyway to pinpoint the cause of the problem?  Thanks in advance!

Edit:
The 4 failed cases reported are all running on Android 5.0, 2 cases on Galaxy A5 and 2 on ZenFone 2.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1260)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

Comment: Look at this; is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24706598/3668646

Comment: Hmm... the different between the other pose from Xose and mine was that all spinners in my app are working as expected, except for these 4 cases. Anyone has experience that resources failed to load some of the time?

Comment: Thanks Xose for pointing me in the right direction.  Turns out there are a few spinners displaying values returned from server-side, and is possible to have null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Xose Sanchez to point out that there are enough information to start investigating even though the stack trace somehow only include Android's classes in this specific situation.

Answering my own question, in my case the app does have a few spinner which display values from the server. So it is entirely possible that the app will attempt to display null values in a Spinner. I added additional null checking code to all these places and hope this can fix the issue.